# Suddenly getting Errno::ECONNREFUSED in UsersController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I can no longer save data to my database and getting `Errno::ECONNREFUSED in UsersController#create`  and `Connection refused - connect(2)`.  This was after I restarted my Mac but have restarted before with no problems.  It looks a connection error between the app and the database but I have no idea how to fix it.

database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: store_development
  pool: 5
  username: name
  password:
```

create action

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      UserMailer.signup_confirmation(@user).deliver
        redirect_to root_url, :flash => {notice: "Welcome" }
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end
```

It fails on the user.save line which leads me to believe it is a connection error.

log file

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-18 15:23:13 -0500
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ZVHiD1fD/wYiTU8zg80BzGih8+VLPyOzPr16Himrv5M=", "user"=>{"name"=>"test", "email"=>"test@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create my account"}
  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36mUser Exists (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('test@example.com') LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "name", "password_digest", "remember_token", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Wed, 18 Dec 2013 20:23:13 UTC +00:00], ["email", "test@example.com"], ["name", "test"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$G03yjEWWIsDJMHGOyDEOp.ACJnYGLXBEfHH0upJYTjeXlNxg6OK/i"], ["remember_token", "a622fb4b8a79d61fb3e7201d00658a3364882f36"], ["updated_at", Wed, 18 Dec 2013 20:23:13 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mROLLBACK[0m
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 73ms

Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:34:in `create'
```

I can easily get into the store_development database and I have started the server by running

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

If I run the stop command this is what I get:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast
pg_ctl: server does not shut down
```

Edit for additional info:  My app can access all the data that is presently there.  I am unable to write new data to the database.  I'm unable to create or update attributes which returns the connection refused error.

Comment: Never used PostGre, but I'd be straight into it's log files if I had something like this.

Comment: sever.log files just show that the server is up and running.

Comment: What no audit logs? Google postgresql logging audit. Though reading further suggests, some sort of permissions problem? Don't know enough, sorry.

Comment: It seems to be a permissions problem, but I have no idea what changed to cause it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.

After my system restart I did not start ElasticSearch again.  The connection refused was from being unable to run the ElasticSearch server and not my Postgres server.